# Uniqueness of solutions in complex linear equations.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, unique-factorization-domains

I will be a teaching assistant in an introductionary course in Calculus in a university next semester. I am looking over the section that covers complex numbers, and allthough the question is a bit pedantic, I would like to offer some rigorous reasoning if the students are curious:

In an exercise the students solve a set of linear equations of the type $2iz = 3+4i \text{ for } z \in \mathbb{C}$, where $z$ is the variable of interest. After we devide by $2i$ and multiply both enumerator and denominator of the R.H.S. with $-2i$, we find a number that solves the equation; $z = 2 - \frac{3}{2}i$. How can we now be certain that we have found all solutions to the original equaion? Should one check that the multiplicative inverse is unique in $\mathbb{C}$? After all, after polar form is introduced, one realizes that a complex number can have several representations, and might begin to wonder if this can lead to otherwise strange behaviour.

Any idea on how to rationalize this in a simple, but exact way, without having to dive into abstract algebra?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @DietrichBurde. I realize there might not other ways to justify this, but as this is a first semester course in calculus, I'm not sure how much there is to gain from introducing notions of abstract algebra. Maybe it's OK to mention that one should be aware that we need some condition on the structure of the number system to be certain that these equations have unique solutions, and let them know that that's for a later course.

Comment: Or one can say, that abstract algebra is nothing to be afraid of, and that in real numbers or complex numbers, every $a\neq 0$ can be multiplied with $1/a$ with $a\cdot \frac{1}{a}=1$, so that $ax=b$ becomes $x=b/a$. This is helpful, I think, and much easier than, say, the "polar form".